# Aparecer campo de input dependendo da seleção do botão radio

Tags: php, javascript, html, radiobutton

Em um formulário, vai ter a opção sim ou não, se sim o usuário vai descrever

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#descreva').hide();
  $('#def').change(function() {
    if ($('#sim') checked) {
        if( $("#sim").is(":checked") == true)
        $('#descreva').show();
    } else {
      $('#descreva').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```
            <div class="campo">
            <label><strong>Possui treinamento: </strong></label>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
            <radio id="def">
            <div>
              <input type="radio" name="devweb" id="sim" value="sim">
              <label for="sim">SIM</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="radio" name="devweb" id="nao" value="nao">
              <label for="nao">NÃO</label>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="text" name="descreva" id="descreva">
            </div>
```

Comment: `if ($('#sim') checked) {` esse if não faz sentido, falta um operador lógico.. de qualquer forma, um radio é um elemento que tem multiplos valores, por isso pode validar o valor direto no lugar de "checked", assim: `if ($('input:radio[name="devweb"]').val() == "sim")`

Answer (score 0):

Algo simples de fazer isso é usando javascript puro mesmo:

```
window.onload = () => {
   var input = document.getElementById('descreva');
   var radio_yes = document.getElementById('sim');
   var radio_no = document.getElementById('nao');
    radio_yes.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        var radio = e.currentTarget;
        if(radio.checked == true) {
          input.disabled=false;
          input.focus();
        } else {
         input.disabled=true;
          input.value='';
        }
    });
    
     radio_no.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        var radio = e.currentTarget;
        if(radio.checked == true) {
          input.value='';
          input.disabled=true;
           input.focus();
        } else {
         input.disabled=false;
        }
    });
}
```

Segue modelo em [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/jk07wsnu/)

Answer (score -1):

Precisa estudar mais o html e javascript, pois tem muitos problemas simples no código:

- `<radio id="def">` não existe um elemento "radio", fora que, do jeito que foi definido ainda ia faltar o fechamento dessa tag
- `if ($('#sim') checked)`  esse if não sentido, o `$('#sim')` vai obter o elemento com id="sim", a partir o máximo que poderia fazer era por exemplo fazer `== null` ou `!= null`, etc, porque é um seletor **para o elemento**, para validar se está "checked", deveria fazer por exemplo `$('#sim').is(':checked')`.
- um radio buttom tem multiplos valores, dai a ultilidade dele em poder "escolher um entre vários valores", e isso acontece porque as opinções tem o mesmo "name", por isso uma forma mais fácil de selecionar é usando: `$('input:radio[name="devweb"]')`.
  Com isso, pode assiciar o evento `change` a todos os radio com o mesmo name, e ainda pode usar pera pegar qual valor foi selecionado, por exemplo `$('input:radio[name="devweb"]').val()`.

Veja abaixo um exemplo de como usar isso:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#descreva').hide();
  // aqui um seletor por name, para pegar todos os radio buttons "devweb"
  $('input:radio[name="devweb"]').change(function() {
    // aqui, this é o radio quem foi clicado, então basta comparar o valor com val()
    if ($(this).val() == "sim") {
        $('#descreva').show();
    } else {
      $('#descreva').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="campo">
    <label><strong>Possui treinamento: </strong></label>
    <!-- removi o elemento "radio" que fato não existe -->
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="devweb" id="sim" value="sim">
      <label for="sim">SIM</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="devweb" id="nao" value="nao">
      <label for="nao">NÃO</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="text" name="descreva" id="descreva">
</div>
```